# Custom Identity in ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web App

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.1

I was following the demo for creating a customized IdentityUser from the Asp Docs.  The default IdentityUser I beleive only records the Username, Email, and Password.  When I would register a new account it would in fact be recorded into the AspNetUser table.  However, in my case I would like to also record things such as FirstName, LastName, DOB, etc... and since the default does not record these I needed to create a custom IdentityUser.  After Following the aspnet docs to implement a custom Identity and updating the html of the views I receive this:

https://gyazo.com/5e1494dccc44d3cd03d24bf48816caf9(screenshot)

I am unsure of where it is receiving the "invalid column name" from, the column names in my VisUser (custom IdentityUser) matches that of the column names in my sql server VisUser Table.

database context:

```
 public class dbContext : IdentityDbContext<VisUser>
    {
        public dbContext(DbContextOptions<dbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<VisUser> VisUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

VisUser

```
public class VisUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(0), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(0), MaxLength(2), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Middle Initial")]
        public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(4), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string VisUserName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress, MaxLength(256), Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string VisEmail { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(6), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Password), Display(Name = "UserPassword")]
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    }
```

Html of the Register Page view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.MiddleInitial"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.MiddleInitial" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.MiddleInitial" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.LastName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.VisEmail"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.VisEmail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.VisEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.VisUserName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.VisUserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.VisUserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.UserPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.UserPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Register Model:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<VisUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<VisUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<VisUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<VisUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public class InputModel : VisUser
        {
        }

        public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new VisUser { UserName = Input.VisUserName, Email = Input.VisEmail };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.UserPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

When I run it I receive errors that my column names cannot be found or do not match.  What I would like to happen would be for the information of VisUser be stored in my VisUser table in sql server and have the relevant information for AspNetUser be stored there too so that I could use operations with SigninManager, UserManager, etc.  Hopefully you can help out and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that your database is not in sync with your code. You need to generate and apply a migration after making these changes so that the database will have backing columns for the new props you're adding.

That said, you've got some other problems here that should be fixed as well. When you inherit from `IdentityUser` don't define a key. `IdentityUser` *already* has a key property. If you want that key to be an int instead of the default of a string, [there's a methodology to do that already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#change-the-primary-key-type).

Likewise, remove the `UserPassword` property. You're going to end up persisting the user's password, probably in plain text, to the database, which is of course a hugely bad idea. The password functionality is already built-in to `IdentityUser`.

Some of this may have been to service the needs of the `InputModel`. However, you should *absolutely* not use an entity as a model in this  way. You need one class specific to the needs of the view (i.e. what you bind your post to and what you display), and one specific to the needs of the database (i.e. what you persist). Don't intermix the two, or you'll have nothing but problems.

Finally, don't impose arbitrary limits like maximum length on user inputs like first and last name, email, etc. There's really no point. All string props are represented as `NVARCHAR`, so they only consume the space they need to consume. For example, if the first name is 10 characters long, it will consume 20 bytes (unicode), whether or not you impose a limit of 50 or not. If there's something that *actually* has a logically-defined length like a social security number, zip code, etc. that's fine. Otherwise, leave it open.

Comment: Thank you, all is well but when I remove the UserPassword Property I get the error that "UserPassword is missing" in my view and code behind the Register Page but since my InputModel : VisUser and my InputModel from the view asks for a Password (for registration of an account) where do I put the password information and use it in UserManager if I take it out from my VisUser identity?  You said it will most likely persist in plain text but then how should I go about registering a user's account with their inputted password if I remove it?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need two separate classes: your entity class for persistence and a view model to be bound to. `UserPassword` can go on your view model, not your entity (i.e. the one that inherits from `IdentityUser`).

Comment: Is my VisUser entity supposed to have 0 references then?  Before when I did the: "InputModel : VisUser" the properties in VisUser were referenced the number of times it was mentioned in the razor page but when I remove it, the properties have 0 references.  How does the application know where the information in the InputModel should be stored in my User table in sql server?

Comment: That's on you. You map over the values from the input model to your entity class. There are libraries like AutoMapper that can make this a bit more automatic, but the whole point is that you should be in charge of what goes into your database, not your user.